# Setting up Apache in Mac OSx

Tags: php, macos, apache, osx-yosemite

I followed this instructions in an Mac Book Air With Yosemite:

http://echo.co/blog/os-x-109-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew

And I guess I messed everything up. When I try to find the apache instances I see these folders.

```
 /private/etc/apache2
 /private/var/log/apache2
 /Users/main/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app-5_4_9/apache2
 /Users/main/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/shared/apache2
 /usr/include/apache2
 /usr/libexec/apache2
 /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/libexec/apache2
 /usr/local/etc/apache2
 /usr/local/var/apache2
 /usr/local/var/log/apache2
```

And for httpd I see:

```
 /usr/local/var/run/apache2/Library/WebServer/share/httpd
 /usr/sbin/httpd
 /usr/share/httpd
```

My question is : How can I revert all these and have the original apache installation for mac?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Though this isn't pertinent to the question directly, XAMPP is a great way to hold all of these options.

Comment: Well I can setup servers in a linux box in about half an hour. And want to configure virtual hosts, secure connections. In a mac I don't even know where the document root is :) Not in ~/Sites or /Library/WebSharing/Documents

Comment: For future readers, please avoid `brew` and other packages. There is no reason. Mac OS X comes with Apache and PHP. You only need to configure and enable them. Please read [installing Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Mac OS X](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-yosemite/).

Comment: Yep understood that in a very painful way. Now need a way to remove them and make it as it was when I bought it.